# Should a class ever have static and non-static members

Tags: language-agnostic, oop

I'm trying to figure out when it would be appropriate for a class to have both static and non-static functions. AKA:

```
$obj = new ClassA;
$obj->doOOPStuff();

$something = ClassA::doStaticStuff();
```

<sup>Note: This example is done in PHP, however the question is language agnostic .</sup>

It seems that if you have a class that is meant to be instantiated, any functions that can be called statically, most likely belong in another class.

Is there any viable cases where I would have a class that used static AND non-static members?

Comment: Here's a pattern I've seen: `class Frob { void tweak() {...}   static void tweakIfNotNull(Frob f) { if (f != null) f.tweak(); } }` This is mainly convenient when the method is something that needs to be recursively applied to every node in a big tree of data. Like *serialize()* or *dispose()*. Each class uses the ifNotNull version on its children.

Comment: Another pattern I've seen is where the static methods are basically a facade for the rest of the class. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Comment: The notion of "static" isn't language-agnostic, it's quite to specific to a small number of them, and even within that set of languages, the best practice varies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One example: when Creation has to happen in a specific way.

```
class Foo {
public:
  static Foo* Create(...params...);

private:
  Foo();
};
```

Comment: +1: That's a usage pattern I've used several times. I find it clearer to make complex creation procedures as their own methods rather than overload the constructor (e.g. `c = C::fromXml(xmldoc)` rather than `c = new C(xmldoc)`).

Comment: You could use a factory in this case

Comment: This pattern is called factory method. I found it heavily used in Objective-C frameworks, although factory method should only be used for convenience constructors IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

Consider `String` class in .NET. It contains a non-static `Split` method which breaks some instance into a `string[]` and a static `Join` method, which takes a `string[]` and transform it into a string again.

A static method is applicable when you don't need to keep any state. So `Math.Sin()` just depends on its parameters and, given same parameters, output will always be the same. A non-static method can have different behavior is called multiple times, as it can keep a internal state.

Answer (score 3):

If the functionality provided by static methods is relevant to that class and its objects, why not. It is pretty common.

Answer (score 2):

- Static method are most often *factory methods*

  ```
  public class MyClass {    
      public static MyClass createMyClass(int a, double b) {..}
      public static MyClass createSubclassOfMyClass(int c, boolean cond) {..}
      public int calculateThis();
      public double calculateThat();
  }
  ```
- Another use is to access some property that is logically bound that that class, but not separately to instances. For example - a cache:

(Note - of course synchronization should be taken into account in this example)

```
public class MyClass {
    public static final Cache cache = new Cache();
    public static void putInCacheIfNeeded(Object obj) {..}
    public static void replaceInCache(Object obj) {..}

    public void doSomethingCacheDependend(Object obj) {
        if (something) {
             MyClass.putInCacheIfNeeded(obj);
        } else {
             MyClass.replaceInCache(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

(Java language for the examples)

Comment: +1, perfect answer if you'd also add private, stateless utility functions.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your constructor has two overloads that both are strings:

```
public class XmlDocument
{
    public static XmlDocument CreateFromFile(string filePath);
    public static XmlDocument CreateFromXml(string xml);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't require static methods. You could create a class for each, or include another parameter, for instance. It's valid, though.

Comment: Yeah, technically you could detect if the string passed in was a valid file path, and if so load from file.

Comment: Why would you want two classes? Also would you really want a constructor like this? `public XmlDocument(string filePath, string xml)`

Comment: @Chacha - Does this look like JavaScript to you? :)

Comment: @Chaos What? Only Javascript gets to have the fun of auto-detection arguments? :)

Comment: @Chacha - Well mainly dynamic languages do such things.

Comment: Could be a public XmlDocument(enum fileType, string content), or maybe public XmlDocument(FilePath filePath). As I said, your approach is also valid, I was just showing alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The static function can provide meaningful name to the constructor.

```
$dialog = DialogFoo::createOpenDialog();
$dialog = DialogFoo::createDocumentOpenDialog();
$dialog = DialogFoo::createImageOpenDialog();
```

It could also be used to enforce [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#PHP) pattern.

```
$dialog = DialogFoo::getInstance()
```

Answer (score 0):

Static class members are most useful where *everything* must either be in an object or be in a global scope; they are less useful in a language such as Python that supports module-level scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I use static methods to instantiate new objects when I dont want the to give access to the constructor. I ensure that any necessary preconditions are carried out on the class before creating and object. In this example I have a counter to return how many objects are created, if I have 10 objects I prevent any more from being instantiated.

```
class foo {
private:
static int count;
foo() {}

public:
static foo bar() {
count++;
if (count<=10){
return new foo;
} else {
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a class has instance methods, here are some good use case for having static methods too:

#### For static utility methods

Such methods apply to any instance, for example [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) in Java.

Use them when you don't want to create a specific instance for the job.

#### For static factory methods

Factory methods are methods that simply instantiate objects like the `getInstance()` and `valueOf()` methods in the Java API. `getInstance()` is the conventional instantiation method in singletons while `valueOf()` are often type-conversion methods, like in [`String.valueOf(int)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29).

Use them to improve performance via object-caching, in interface-based frameworks (like the [Collections Framework](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html) in Java) where you may want to return a subtype, to implement singletons (cough).

Answer (score 0):

In general, static functions produce functionality highly related to class itself. It may be some helper functions, factory methods etc. In this case all functionality contains in one place, it correspond to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY) principle, increases [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) and reduces [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29).